# Segmentation Fault when retrieving value from pointer in another function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a beginner with C and am running into the following problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void myFunc(char **data);

int main() {
    char **header;
    myFunc(header);
    printf("[In main] %s\n", header[1]); // This gives segmentation fault
    return 0;
}

void myFunc(char **data) {
    data = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    data[0] = "test";
    data[1] = "test 2";
    printf("[In myFunc] %s\n", data[1]); // This works just fine
}
```

I can retrieve and print the value of the pointer within the function I allocated the memory for it, but outside of this (in main), it gives segmentation fault.

Comment: to make it compile cleanly change: `char **header;` to `char **header = NULL;

Comment: in C, when calling `malloc()`, 1) do not cast the returned value as it is a `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutter the code and adds headaches to debugging and maintenance of the code.  2) before using the returned value, always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this kind of line: `data[0] = "test";` needs to be: `(*data)[0] = "test";`   This line: `myFunc(header);` passes the contents of `header` what needs to be passed is the address of header: `myFunc( &header );`

Comment: this line: `data = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));` is not setting the contents of `header` to point to the malloc'd area.  it should be: `*data = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));`  And, of course, check *data for !=NULL before actually using the pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is a little more fundamental to your use of pointers and what happens when you pass a pointer as an *argument* to a function. When you pass a pointer to a function (just like any variable), the function receives a *copy of* that pointer (or variable). Meaning that when `header` is passed to `myFunc`, `myFunc` receives a copy of `header` as `data` (with its very own, and very different, *address*):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myFunc(char **data);

int main() {
    char **header;
    printf ("\n the address of header in main: %p\n", &header);
    myFunc(header);
    printf("[In main] %s\n", header[1]); // This gives segmentation fault
    return 0;
}

void myFunc(char **data) {
    data = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    printf ("\n the address of data in myFunc: %p\n", &data);
    data[0] = "test";
    data[1] = "test 2";
    printf("[In myFunc] %s\n", data[1]); // This works just fine
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/myFunc1

 the address of header in main: 0x7ffd112e27b8

 the address of data in myFunc: 0x7ffd112e2798
[In myFunc] test 2
Segmentation fault
```

**Note:** how the address of `header` in in `main` is `0x7ffd112e27b8`, but when you allocate memory for `data` in `myFunc`, you are assigning the starting address for the new block of memory to a pointer at `0x7ffd112e2798`. Nothing in `main` knows anything about memory address `0x7ffd112e2798`.

**How Do We Fix it?**

Just like you do every other time you wish to pass a variable to a function, update that variable, and have the changed value reflected back in the calling function (`main` here) -- you pass the *address of* that variable to the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myFunc(char ***data);

int main() {
    char **header;
    printf ("\n the address of header in main: %p\n", &header);
    myFunc(&header);  /* passing address of header to myFunc */
    printf("[In main] %s\n", header[1]);
    return 0;
}

void myFunc(char ***data) {
    *data = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    printf ("\n the address of data in myFunc: %p\n", data);
    (*data)[0] = "test";
    (*data)[1] = "test 2";
    printf("[In myFunc] %s\n", (*data)[1]);
}
```

Now that you have passed the *address of* `header` to `myFunc` as `data`, when you allocate memory for `*data`, you are allocating memory and returning the pointer to the same address for `header` in `main`. Which allows:

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/myFunc2

 the address of header in main: 0x7ffdd72b1968

 the address of data in myFunc: 0x7ffdd72b1968
[In myFunc] test 2
[In main] test 2
```

**Making Use of the Return from `myFunc`**

You can also *return* the starting address for the new block of memory to `main` and accomplish the same thing, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **myFunc(char **data);

int main() {
    char **header;
    printf ("\n the address of header in main: %p\n", &header);
    header = myFunc(header);
    printf("[In main] %s\n", header[1]); // This works fine too
    return 0;
}

char **myFunc(char **data) {
    data = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    printf ("\n the address of data in myFunc: %p\n", &data);
    data[0] = "test";
    data[1] = "test 2";
    printf("[In myFunc] %s\n", data[1]); // This works just fine
    return data;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/myFunc3

 the address of header in main: 0x7ffee22e3298

 the address of data in myFunc: 0x7ffee22e3278
[In myFunc] test 2
[In main] test 2
```

Now `main` knows about the address allocated to `data` in `myFunc` by virtue of assigning the return to `header`.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you need to allocate the `data` before calling a function to work on it. You did it the other way around, by allocating `data` inside the function, it is known inside the function itself but not in `main`.

In this particular case, you need to:

- Allocate the memory for `data` before calling `myFunc()` (inside that function itself you don't need to allocate the memory for `data`):

`header = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));`

`myFunc(header);`

- Inside `myFunc()`, there is no need to allocate memory for the two pointers to char as you are using string literals:

`data[0] = "test";`

However, it is *possible* to allocate memory for individual char pointer as well:

`data[0] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));`

In that case, you can do `strcpy` or some other methods to set the content of `data[0]` and `data[1]`

---

Alternatively, all allocation can be done inside `myFunc()`, but you need to change the prototype to return the proper pointer.

```
char** myFunc() {
    char **data = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    data[0] = "test";
    data[1] = "test 2";
    printf("[In myFunc] %s\n", data[1]);

    return data;
}

int main() {
    char **header;
    header = myFunc();
    printf("[In main] %s\n", header[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! Just to clarify, once I pass the memory into the function, can I allocate more memory to the elements of array within the function? Like this
    data[0] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));

Comment: I think you need two levels of memory allocation; in `main` allocate the memory for `header` (which is a pointer to pointer to char). In `myFunc` you need to allocate for individual char pointer.

Comment: There's no reason at all to copy the strings. Using direct assignment is perfectly OK in the above example. The problem with OP's code is a *lack* of more direct assignments: the actual mistake is in failing to return a value from `myFunc` such that `header` is never actually set.

Comment: Ok my bad on that particular point of direct assignment - edited that. Apart from that, is there anything wrong about memory allocation in the answer? Can you post a different answer to make your points clear.

Comment: Yes. There's no need to allocate memory outside `myFunc`. You can return allocated memory from functions: OP's mistake is in not returning a value to assign to `header`. That's all; you're *massively* overthinking the question.

Comment: >There's no need to allocate memory outside myFunc. There's no need to allocate memory outside myFunc. 

Agree, the prototype should be changed then `char** myFunc()`. For the original prototype, the pointer must be allocated first before calling the function.